# How do I play with my friend in my singleplayer world easily on Minecraft PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My cousin and I want to play Minecraft together but I don't want to join a multiplayer server or use mods. How can we do this?

Comment: If you and your cousin live together and use the same internet, it's possible to play together using LAN.

Answer (score 2):

First press "Open to Lan". Then choose one of the options below:

---

Option 1)

Invite your friend to come to your home. Use the same router, and your computer will appear in your friends' multiplayer menu.

---

Option 2)

Download [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net) and connect to the same room.

---

Option 3)

Pretty complex option. Not suggested if you don't know what to do!

When you press "Open to Lan" minecraft should say: Server hosted in port XXXXX

Go to Router settings and open that port.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect your PC/laptops to the same router, one of you can host the game on LAN and the other can simply join in.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Hamachi, its a program what can make simulated lan, when you have two computers with Minecraft in the same lan click the option to open your world to lan and anyone can join.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but me and my friend did it before. You have to open to LAN and tell or write down the # and your cousin has to either wait for it to pop up in the multiplayer area or you have to figure out the IP address of your computer and enter it the add ":" that next to it, then add the LAN #. Hope it works for you. But you have to be on the same network/wifi. Good luck!!

Comment: I meant enter ":" next to the IP address

Comment: You can edit your post for further improvements. Just click the [edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/285728/edit) link.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek (You can even create an active [edit] link in comments, which will go straight to the parent post's edit screen, by typing `[edit]` in the comment.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie OK. So I just take the link location and copy it?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Just literally type `[edit]` and it magically does it for you when the comment is posted. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ah, didn't know that (didn't stumble across anything simmialr on Meta), thanks :)